# can I use multiple <address> tags on a page?

Tags: html

I think I saw somewhere that you should use only one `<address>` tag if it refers to the body, but I can't find that in the spec, so is it fine?

Because I have a header with the phone number on one side  and on the other side the location of the restaurant, and the logo in the center:

[image]

And another thing: in the spec it says that I can't put content that *isn't* contact information, but does the time you are available for phone calls considered to be contact information, or can I put it directly in a `<small>` tag, after the phone number?

```
<!-- for some reason I can't type the header tag -->
    <address>
      555 555 5555
    </address>
    <aside>10 AM - Midnight</aside>

    <img src="logo" alt="DevCamp's fantastic Fries">

    <address>
      123 Any Street<br>
      Scottsdale, AZ,<br>
      85251
     </address>
```

And if I can do:

```
<address>
   <p>555 555 5555</p>
   <!-- is it semantically correct? -->
   <p><small>10 AM - Midnight</small></p>
 </address>
```

Comment: The W3C spec does seem to phrase it that way, but it's not a hard specification requirement, so I wouldn't worry about pleasing some spec authors who couldn't be bothered to consider realistic use cases more broadly. Whether search engines would get tripped up by it is a separate question worth investigating, although I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

after reading this  : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/address ,

i dont see where is the problem , it's not too much to make impossible to understand that both part of the company adress.

Comment: I'm asking if is ok to have multiple <address> tags for one page that aren't in an <article> and for the content to be something related to the contact information (like the time available for contact) but isn't directy a contact info. - Because I read somewhere that semantically, there should be only one <address> for page

Comment: @Colin if you look close the example on the page there is more information than the simple adress  and when you read  you can see that in a article that refer to the author and generaly (outside article) to the company, website owner etc.

Comment: after looking more i found that you can create an adress object in javascript like described here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_address.asp  So i think if you worry about the integrity of your adress information you can display the both sidebloc of your logo as regular div and use this object to maniputate your adress informations